# Bootstrap template design and navbar problem

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am new with html and bootstrap but I tried to create a bootstrap template, actually I tried to make a test theme by downloading the "starter template" code from getbootstrap.com, but when I launch the code or even when I make some changes the navigation bar and design looks horrible. Even when I am not changing anything the design and navigation bar looks horrible.

Here is my code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test theme</title>
  <link rel="stylesheets" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test theme</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
      <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /.container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have Bootstrap properly included?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/
I don’t see that in your code, even though it seems to be complete HTML file.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `bootstrap` you need to properly **hook it up**. Here more about [it](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/)  Below simple example(Navbar) with properly link `Bootstrap 5`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Navbar Example</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown link
              </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```